# How can I convert this piece of JSON to POJO?

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo, objectmapper

I am pulling a JSON file from the Clash Royale web API and trying to fully convert it to a Java object using the Jackson ObjectMapper class. The json file I am pulling describes a Clash Royale player. The file includes a bunch of normal json key-value pairs, json objects, and arrays of objects. Normal key-value pairs are easy to integrate into my Java Player class because they are simply field variables. The first nested object I came across in the json file is the "arena" object. I created a Java class for an arena with the appropriate variables and then created an arena variable in my Player class, which worked well. However, the problem came with the next piece of json which describes "leagueStatistics"... I don't know how to represent that in a java class. Would it be a "LeagueStatistics" class with an array list of season objects or something along those lines? I am kind of new to reading json and would appreciate any tips. I will include a pic of my Player class and the json in question. [image: Json that has me confused]
[image: My Player POJO]

Also, is it appropriate to call the Clash API a web service? API seems to be a loosely used word with many definitions which makes it confusing.

I figured out how to configure the ObjectMapper class so that it does not throw an error when it comes across json objects that I did not program into my POJO correctly, such as the "leagueStatistics" object. I also know I can ignore specific objects using the configuration. I know it may not make sense to convert such a large json file to an object, I am just trying to learn how this stuff works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you please provide your json content and source code as text so other can copy/paste them?

Comment: You should prefer to provide code between code tags rather than as an image.

Comment: after you create an `ObjectMapper` using your custom configuration (as you said), you can use it to read and parse json from a string or a file. You just need to pass the source and your java model: `Player player = mapper.readValue(new File("./player.json"), Player.class);`